# Insert records into two tables having common column

Tags: sql, jsp

I want to insert into my name `stud` in which foreign key is `t_id` which is primary key in table (teacher) so I want to know the query for that.

```
INSERT into stud where s_id,Name,t_id,username,password where s_id="+s_id)
```

this is the query i am writing in jsp page...but it is giving me the error

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`userdb`.`stud`, CONSTRAINT `stud_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`t_id`) REFERENCES `teachers` (`t_id`));
```

Comment: Check if the record exists in another table to insert their correct relationship,otherwise this error appears.

Comment: your sql statement makes no sense at all... what do you want to insert and into what table?

Comment: this is a servlet and for adding the records i hv made a jsp page ...so wen i click on to the button register then values will be shown lik form i need to fill...it will take dynamic values.

Comment: I find it quite worrying that, that's the error message you are getting. Would have expected something like error in sql near where.

Answer (score 0):

```
("INSERT INTO stud(s_id,Name,t_id,username,password) 
VALUES ( " + s_id + "," + Name + "," + t_id + "," + username + ","  + password + ")")
```

This is the correct parameterized **INSERT** query syntax.

Your query had two **WHERE** clauses which were written incorrectly, plus your **VALUES** clause was not there, plus you didn't mention the column names explicitly in your syntax. Hence, your query doesn't make any sense at all.

p.s. I used dummy data. Insert appropriate and relevant data in your query. Also, I assumed your parameter names are exactly the same as your columns' names. Please modify your parameters according to your code if necessary.